# ltsp-built-client error

Tags: linux, installation, thin-client, ltsp

I am facing some issues while building a thin client using the `ltsp-build-client`, it says an error.

Error is:

```
I: Retrieving Release
E: Failed getting release file file://root/ISO/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso/dists/squeeze/Release
error: LTSP client installation ended abnormally
```

My Command is:

```
ltsp-build-client --mirror file://root/ISO/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso --security-mirror none --accept-unsigned-packages
```

I am referring this URL http://wiki.debian.org/LTSP/Howto.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

There is a point in the build process that the container you are "building" takes over, and starts running commands itself.  It is at this point that you are getting the error you see.

The error is due to the client populating it's own apt source list using the mirror you gave it (file://root/ISO/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso in this case).  However, when the client tries to do an `apt-get update`, it can't, because relative to the client's `/` there is no `/root/ISO/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso`.

To avoid this, simply tell it to copy the apt source list from the server verbatim instead.

The argument you want is `--copy-sourceslist`.

The full command would be (working off what you listed above):

```
ltsp-build-client --copy-sourceslist --mirror file://root/ISO/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso --security-mirror none --accept-unsigned-packages
```

Also, it was hell finding the commands again, in the end I had to just install LTSP on my workstation and run `ltsp-build-client --extra-help`.  For my own sanity, and other looking for the extra-help message on Google, I'm pasting it here:

**From `ltsp-server_5.2.16-0ubuntu7`:**

```
$ ltsp-build-client --extra-help
LTSP Build Client usage:

  ltsp-build-client <options>

Regular options:
    --dist                     set the distribution to be used for install
    --extra-help               display help for all available commandline options
    --help                     display this help message
    --mirror                   set the mirror location

Advanced options:
    --accept-unsigned-packages allow unsigned packages during install
    --apt-keys                 include the listed keys in the apt keyring
    --arch                     set the target architecture
    --base                     set the default base install directory
    --chroot                   set the name of the chroot
    --components               set the components to be used in mirror
    --config                   load a user specific configuration file
    --copy-package-cache       cache downloaded packages
    --copy-package-lists       copy apt Packages files from server
    --copy-sourceslist         use the servers sources.list instead of generating one
    --debconf-seeds            load debconf seeding in the chroot after install
    --debug                    enable debug support
    --early-mirror             add a mirror, which takes priority over the default mirror
    --early-packages           set the list of packages to install after base-install is completed
    --enable-popcon            enable popularity-contest in the chroot
    --exclude                  exclude packages from the initial chroot
    --extra-mirror             add a mirror, with lower priority than the default mirror
    --fat-client-desktop       run most or all applications locally
    --fat-client               run most or all applications locally
    --http-proxy               use specified http proxy
    --install-debs-dir         install to the chroot all the .deb files contained in the provided directory
    --keep-packages            keep cache of downloaded package files
    --kiosk                    a simple webkiosk mode
    --late-packages            list of packages to install as part of the final installation
    --locale                   set the default locale
    --ltsp-cluster             enable LTSP-Cluster
    --mount-cdrom              mounts CDROM before installation
    --mount-package-cache      mount package cache dir from server
    --mount-package-dir        mount a server directory as the chroot package cache dir
    --mythbuntu                create a Mythbuntu fat client.
    --mythbuntu-user-credentials Mythbuntu: specify login credentials as username:password
    --no-guess-proxy           do not autodetect apt proxy configuration
    --pin-dist                 distribution to set up apt pinning
    --pin-packages             list of packages to install from the pinned distribution
    --prompt-rootpass          prompt to set the root password, defaults to disabled
    --purge-chroot             purge existing LTSP chroot if present
    --security-mirror          set the security mirror location
    --serial-console           enable serial console
    --skipimage                force to skip the squashfs build (for debian-installer)
    --skip-upgrade             skip upgrade of installed packages
    --tftp-dirs                TFTP dirs to update kernel in (space-separated)
    --updates-mirror           set the update mirror location
```

Comment: The only other possible cause of the problem I see is this: `E: Failed getting release file file://root/ISO/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso/dists/squeeze/Release`.  It looks like you are trying to build an Ubuntu client on a Debian Squeeze LTSP server...  The files it's looking for (Debian release files) don't exist on the Ubuntu CD.  This may, or may not be fixed by the command above.  It depends on whether the error is happening inside the client or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
--dist [DISTRIBUTION OF THE OS]
```

You should add the above at the end of the command.